# How to convert string 06-09-2019 14:34 date to UTC 06/09/2019 14:34

Tags: python-3.x

How to convert string which I need to UTC?
06-09-2019 14:34 to  06/09/2019 14:34

```
date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(context.beginning_date_attribute, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

this code produces 2019-09-06 14:45:00 and I dont want seconds also here

Comment: this is not duplicate there is nothinhg about date format which I needed here

Comment: The answers all reference the official Python documentation, which gives you the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what *context.beginning_date_attribute* is, but here is how to reformat your timestamp.

```
from datetime import datetime

GMT_timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
print (GMT_timestamp)
# outputs 
2019-09-06 14:05:22.215443

# milliseconds removed from GMT timestamp
reformatted_GMT_timestamp = GMT_timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
print (reformatted_GMT_timestamp)
# outputs 
2019-09-06 14:05

reformatted_timestamp = datetime.strptime('2019-09-06 14:05:22.215443', '%Y-%m-%d 
%H:%M:%S.%f').strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
print (reformatted_timestamp)
# outputs 
06/09/2019 14:05
```

Comment: context.beginning_date_attribute = UTC +2 in this format 09/09/2019 06:25

Comment: ```date_for_beginning_date = datetime.strptime(context.beginning_date_attribute, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')``` == 09/09/2019 10:10 its great !! I just need to convert it to UTC

Comment: @ranger thanks for letting me know about the date string.  I'm glad that I could help you in someway.  If I did help you please accept the answer or upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using replace

```
date2.replace("-", "/")
```

Comment: I got Unexpected type(s) warning

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
# current date and time
now = datetime.now()

s1 = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
# mm/dd/YY H:M:S format
```

Comment: thanks but I want to pass string with date not current date and also no seconds needed just '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'

Comment: ```                                                                                                                       utc_offset = datetime.utcnow() - datetime.now()
        local_datetime = datetime.strptime(raw_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
        local_to_utc_datetime = local_datetime + utc_offset
        return local_to_utc_datetime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') this works for me ```